# Drawing a circle in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to overlay a circle over the points I have plotted. This is the script I use for the circle.

```
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced size 3in,3in
set yrange [0:6]
set xrange [0:6]
set xtics 1
set ytics 1
set grid
set output 'Interface.eps'
set object 1 circle at 3,3 size 2 fc rgb "red" lw 2
plot 0
```

The circle hence plotted is

[image]

If you observe, here the dimensions of circle along the Y axis is wrong, with the radius of circle being "2" and centre at [3,3].

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, get your graph with identical dimensions (in pixels).

```
set size ratio -1
```